# calculate the time difference for same column in Spotfire

Tags: time, expression, difference, spotfire

I am a beginner for Spotfire. I have a problem about the difference calculation for the some column value.  A sample table could be like this:

```
id  timestamp              state
 1  7/1/2016 12:00:01 AM    1
 2  7/1/2016 12:00:03 AM    0
 3  7/1/2016 12:00:04 AM    1
 4  7/1/2016 12:00:06 AM    0
 5  7/1/2016 12:00:09 AM    1
 6  7/1/2016 12:00:10 AM    0
 7  7/1/2016 12:00:12 AM    1
```

I want to calculate the time difference for the timestamp when the state is 1, 
the final table I want to have is:

```
id  timestamp              state  time_diffence
 3  7/1/2016 12:00:04 AM    1     3
 5  7/1/2016 12:00:09 AM    1     5
 7  7/1/2016 12:00:12 AM    1     3
```

it seems that I should identify an expression for the calculation, but I have not idea for the calculation just for one parameter :(. somebody could help me ?

still one more small question: what if the timestamp column value is just number value, how can i calculate the difference, is there any related function like DateDiff() here? for example:

```
id  times state
 1  12    1
 2   7    0
 3  10    1
 4  11    0
 5   6    1
 6   9    0
 7   7    1
```

the result could be :

```
id  times state  diffence
 3  10    1      -2
 5   6    1      -4
 7   7    1       1
```

**after running the code: i have the error as below:**

[image]

for the row if it has the same time stamp as the last previous row, the difference will keep same as before, but actually the difference for the rows which have same time stamp would be as 0

thanks for your help :)

Comment: Is the data always sorted by time? This is important.

Comment: yes, it is sorted by time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is sorted in ascending order by `[timestamp]` before you import it, you can partition using the `Previous` function with `Over` where the `[state]=1`.

Insert a calculated column with this expression:

```
If([state]=1,DateDiff("ss",Min([timestamp]) OVER (Previous([timestamp])),[timestamp]))
```

You will see it populated in your table like the below:

[image: table]

Then if you ONLY want to see the rows that have the difference you mentioned, on your table you can...

`Right Click > Properties > Data > Limit data using expression >`

And insert the expression: `[time_difference] > 1`

This will result in this table:

[image: table2]

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. still a short question, if the column value is just number, how can i calculate the difference, is there any related function like DateDiff()?

Comment: Yes but it's off topic to this question so I'd open another one to adhere to how stack overflow works and we can continue there @ZAWD

Comment: hi , thanks, have not idea for the rules, sorry for that, and i have I opened another question topic :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304042/calculate-the-difference-for-same-column-in-spotfire

Comment: No worries at all @ZAWD. If an answer is correct you want to accept it by clicking the check mark. If you find one helpful you want to upvote it. Other than that your question was perfect, clear and with expected output. I'm on holiday but will answer Monday if someone doesn't

Comment: hi , hope this question is not too late to be asked, after running the code in the calculated column, i have an error, for the row if it has the same time stamp  as the last previous row, the difference will keep same as before, but actually the difference for the rows which have same time stamp would be as 0