# calculate the difference for same column in Spotfire

Tags: calculated-columns, difference, spotfire

I am a beginner for Spotfire. I have a problem about the difference calculation for the some column value.

I have opened a similar question for the date difference calculation, see:[calculate the time difference for same column in Spotfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273327/calculate-the-time-difference-for-same-column-in-spotfire)

how can i calculate the difference for the same column, is there any related function like DateDiff() here? for example:

```
id  times state
 1  12    1
 2   7    0
 3  10    1
 4  11    0
 5   6    1
 6   9    0
 7   7    1
```

the result could be :

```
id  times state  diffence
 3  10    1      -2
 5   6    1      -4
 7   7    1       1
```

For example : for the first difference:
 **-2** = **10** (the third row, the state is 1) - **12**(the first row, the state is 1)

thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi zawd, how are you coming up with the difference? I don't follow the logic here..

Comment: @niko his data stays sorted I think and he looks at the state column. If it's 1 subtract TIMES column from previous times column where bit is 1. I'm with minimal service so can't answer

Comment: @scsimon aha I see! Thanks for pointing out. It's a race then to see which of us can get to a PC with a good connection first xD

Comment: hi , all, thanks for the attention, i have amended the text to make it more clear to understand :) any suggestions and questions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ZAWD - Please try this over expression.

```
If([state]=1,[times] - Sum([times]) over (previous([id])),null)
```

[image]